# Pullback of a section of a trivial fibration along a fibration

Tags: category-theory, model-categories

Assume we have a category of fibrant objects and a pullback square in it, where both vertical maps are fibrations and the lower horizontal map is a weak equivalence, call it $i$. Assume further that $i$ is a section of a trivial fibration $\pi$.

I once saw the claim that the pullback of $\pi$ which is again a trivial fibration exhibits the upper horizontal map in my original square as the section of this trivial fibration or in other words: the pullback of a section of a trivial fibration along a fibration is again a section of a trivial fibration. Does somebody know the proof for this?

Sorry for the unhandy text but I cant use tikzcd here which I usually use for my diagrams.

Comment: You can send a quiver link.

Comment: What is a quiver link?

Comment: https://q.uiver.app/

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $i:X\rightarrow Y$ is a section of the trivial fibration $p:Y\overset{\sim}{\twoheadrightarrow} X$. Suppose that $f:X'\twoheadrightarrow X$ is a fibration. Consider the pullback $Y'$ of $p$ and $f$ as in
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
Y' &\overset{\sim}{\twoheadrightarrow}& X'\\
g\downarrow && \downarrow f\\
Y &\overset{\sim}{\underset{p}{\twoheadrightarrow}}& X
\end{array}$$
where the top arrow is a trivial fibration as pullback of a trivial fibration along a fibration.

The commutative square given by two parallel horizontal identities and the two vertical morphisms being $f$ gives rise to a commutative diagram
$$\tag{$\ast$}\begin{array}{ccccc}
X' &\underset{j}{\rightarrow} & Y' & \overset{\sim}{\underset{q}\twoheadrightarrow} & X'\\
f\downarrow &&g\downarrow&&f\downarrow\\
X &\underset{i}{\rightarrow} & Y & \overset{\sim}{\underset{p}\twoheadrightarrow}&X
\end{array}$$
in which the top and bottom composites are the identity. Note since the outer and right square are pullback squares, so is the left square. But this shows that the pullback of a section of a trivial fibration along a fibration is a section of a trivial fibration.

Note that in this argument it is essential to know that the morphism $g$ is given by the pullback of $f$ along $p$. If you only start with a pullback square
$$\begin{array}{ccc}
X' & \overset{j'}\rightarrow & Y'\\
f\downarrow && \downarrow g\\
X & \underset{i}\rightarrow & Y
\end{array}$$
it is not clear, whether $g$ is the pullback of $f$ along $p$. If this is is **not** the case, then $j'$ need not be a section of a trivial fibration, since it need not even be a split monomorphism (as a counterexample to the letter claim any two nonempty subsets with empty intersection will do). But if $g$ **is** the pullback of $f$ along $p$ we get a commutative diagram
$$\tag{$\ast\ast$}\begin{array}{ccccc}
X' &\underset{j'}{\rightarrow} & Y' & \overset{\sim}{\underset{q}\twoheadrightarrow} & X'\\
f\downarrow &&g\downarrow&&f\downarrow\\
X &\underset{i}{\rightarrow} & Y & \overset{\sim}{\underset{p}\twoheadrightarrow}&X
\end{array}$$
by pasting the two given pullback squares. Since both the left square in $(\ast)$ and the left square in $(\ast\ast)$ are pullback squares of the diagram $X \overset{i}\rightarrow Y \overset{g}\leftarrow Y'$ there exists a unique isomorphism $x:X'\cong X'$ induced from the pullbacks, which in particular satisfies $jx=j'$. But then $qj' = qjx=x$ implies $x^{-1}qj'=1_{X'}$ and thus shows that $j'$ is a section of the trivial fibration $x^{-1}q$.

Comment: You've shown that the pullback of every split epimorphism is a split epimorphism, and more precisely that pullbacks of sections of the former yield sections of the latter. This does not answer the question which is about retractions of pullbacks of split monomorphisms being given by pullbacks of retractions (in the special case where the retraction is an acyclic fibration).

Comment: It seems like there are two questions and I answered the second (I still believe that my answer shows that the pullback of a section of a trivial fibration is a section of a trivial fibration, which comes in op‘s post after *in other words*). The first question is what you are referring to. My last paragraph was meant to indicate how to go about this, but I will elaborate on it.

Comment: @JonasLinssen, you may find the statement in the video recording of the higher category I lecture at about 11 minutes. I want to transfer it to categories of fibrant objects.

Comment: Hi Roland :) What lecture was it specifically? We didn't really speak about categories of fibrant objects up until HCat3, so I am not really aware, when Prof. Cisinski did an argument like the one you were asking about.

Comment: HCat1 lecture 20 at about 11minutes. I would like to apply this argument to show that in a category of fibrant objects all fibrations are W-local in the sense of https://cisinski.app.uni-regensburg.de/CatLR.pdf  7.2.22 to apply 7.2.25

Comment: I am not sure whether this is actually true. It seems to me that this would imply that the pullback of a weak equivalence along a fibration is again a weak equivalence (by choosing the lower right morphism in 7.2.22 as the identity), but if you take a non-right-proper model category and restrict to its category of fibrant objects this should fail…

Comment: My counterexample is nonsense, see https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category+of+fibrant+objects#SimpleConsequences lemma 4.10, which proves that in a category of fibrant objects, the pullback of a weak equiv along a fibration is a weak equiv. This should answer your question to the positive…

Comment: Thank you, this was what I needed. The key fact was actually hidden in the factorization lemma, that we can factor any morphism into a section of a trivial fibration and a fibration.